# DXL Question: How List All Attribute Names in a Module

Tags: attributes, col, ibm-doors

I have the following DXL code:

*Module m = current*

*Column c*

*for c in m do{ print attrName c "\n" }*

When I run it I get a listing of only the column names that are **currently visible** in the opened DOORS module.  How can I get a listing of **all** column names in the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse columns with attributes.

Columns are related to representing information, attributes store information. And remember that there are object attributes and module attributes.
That being said:  The DXL reference manual has the chapter "for object attributes in module" in chapter 20 "Attributes". It says

```
for object attributes in module
Syntax
for objAttrName in module do {
 ...
}

where:
    objAttrName is a string variable
    module is a variable of type Module

Operation
Assigns the string objAttrName to be each successive attribute that is defined for objects in module.

Example

string objAttrName
for objAttrName in (current Module) do print objAttrName "\n"
```

Comment: Thanks Mike - *exactly* what I was looking for.